# Create Manual Link in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I have created a line chart using below code.

```
select * from ( 
select
'f?p=&APP_ID.:41:&SESSION.:SUBMIT:&DEBUG.::P41_FROM_STOCK_ID,P41_TO_STOCK_ID:s.from_id,s.to_id' LINK,
s.from_id || '-' || s.to_id LABEL,

        sum(util.find_usage_from_stock(MATERIAL_THIKNESS,s.from_id,s.to_id)) -
        sum(util.find_sheets_sold(MATERIAL_THIKNESS,s.from_id,s.to_id)) diff  
  from material m, (select lag(stock_id, 1, stock_id) over (order by stock_date) from_id, stock_id to_id                                             
                    from STOCK
                    where stock_time not like 'NEW_STOCK') s
 where m.active like 'Y'
 group by s.from_id,s.to_id
 order by s.from_id desc
) 
 WHERE rownum <= 20
ORDER BY rownum DESC;
```

when click on a circle in line chart, should redirect to a link. but i have trouble with `LINK` in above query. when i click on a circle, redirect to url like below.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=110:41:2026929503975702:SUBMIT:NO::P41_FROM_STOCK_ID,P41_TO_STOCK_ID:s.from_id,s.to_id
```

but i need to assign values into `s.from_id,s.to_id` in above url when i click on a circle in my chart.
how can i do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't you just need to take the values from the query and concatenate those to your link string?, like this:

```
'f?p='||:APP_ID||':41:'||:APP_SESSION||':SUBMIT:'||:DEBUG||'::P41_FROM_STOCK_ID,P41_TO_STOCK_ID:'||s.from_id||','||s.to_id LINK
```

Comment: Also highly recommend not using &SESSION. in SQL, use bind variables instead.

Comment: @ScottWe very true. This was in 2012, before I got smarts ;-) I'll update the answer!

Comment: no doubt, but I like to make a note for future readers when I see stuff like this. nice work.